# Javascript, render objects in a tree list

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, treeview, analysis

I try to build a small tool for get the structure of my js running in a browser.

I create a gits for that: https://gist.github.com/M3kH/6615963

But is no way to make work on the browser without crashes.

- What you think I'm doing wrong?
- Did you think Async way would prevent browser crashes?
- How can I get the property of a element is a **function**? I need to
  executed it?
- I have some cases like in jquery plugins where looks like:

  ```
  ;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
      $.fn.namePlugin = function(options) {
          options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.namePlugin.options,options );
          return this.each(function(){
              // This is the builder
              $.fn.namePlugin.options.functionA();
          });
      }
      // Here where I fill all the functions
      $.fn.namePlugin.options = { functionA: function(){} };
  });
  ```

  Did you think I have some ways for get the return function as a loop?

I would like to build an utility for get the list of the function, for document it in a second moment.

Thanks in advance,
Mauro.

Comment: are you trying to do like what Firebug does in its scripts section?

Comment: Not exactly, I want try to make the Tree Dom view of Firebug.